# Не отображается value: 3 в объекте

Tags: javascript, объекты

JS

```js
var array = [];

function arrayToList(array) {
  let list = {}
  Object.assign(list, {
    value: array[0]
  }, {
    rest: {
      value: array[1],
      rest: {
        value: array[2],
        rest: null
      }
    }
  });
  return list;
};

console.log(arrayToList([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: Что значит «не отображается»?

Comment: судя по сниппету все отображается

Comment: На codepen.io в консоли выводятся значения value:1 и value:2, а value:3 нет.

Comment: На codepen.io консоль просто не показывает всю глубину вложенных объектов. Но по факту они там есть.

Answer (score 0):

В [спецификации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) сказано:

> Метод `Object.assign()` копирует из исходных объектов в целевой объект только *перечисляемые* и *собственные* свойства.

Поэтому то что вы делаете, невозможно.

**upd**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой lodash, в ней есть разные вариации копирования объектов (например, _.cloneDeep)